# "Frei" vs "gratis" vs "umsonst" vs "kostenlos"

Tags: difference, meaning, adjective, vocabulary

I think *kostenlos* and *frei* have the same meaning, but I really wonder if there is a very thin difference among these adjectives.

Comment: Related: [Is There More Than One German Word For “Free”?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/1972/9551)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These words are often used in the same context, but each one of them has contexts, in which the other ones are less likely to be used.

When it comes to buying things, the one you should use is *kostenlos*. It literally means “without any costs”.

*Gratis* implies the same thing, but is in my experience used in cases, where someone tries to convince you or has already convinced you to buy something and then they or you highlight, that there is something else you’ll get (only) when buying, which you don’t need to pay for. When I hear the word gratis, I think of some situation, where there is a catch to a purchase and something is not as *kostenlos* as others want you to believe it is.

With *umsonst* you have to be a bit careful. For example in English you could say “Your efforts are for naught.” This is a case in which you could use *umsonst*. *Umsonst*’s actual meaning is closer to “without any use” than to anything implying that there are no costs. However, people use it for that as well. Another example of good usage: “Nun ist all unsere Arbeit umsonst”, which doesn’t mean that the work was not paid, but that the original goal of that work has either become irrelevant or impossible to reach.

*Frei* I’d say is the most general word of those. *Frei* is related to *Freiheit* (Freedom). In English you could probably say “I got that book for free”, but in German you couldn’t say “I habe das Buch für frei bekommen.” There are few cases, in which *frei* refers to the costs of something. There is for example *Freibier*, which means everyone gets some beer without having to pay for it.
When you use *frei*, try to use it when it is really about freedom and not about the costs. Here are some examples for the usage of *frei*:

- Die Gedanken sind frei. – One’s free to think whatever one likes, but it’s got nothing to do with any costs.
- Sie wollte frei sein wie ein Vogel. – She wanted to be free like a bird.

Oh and btw.: There is also *kostenfrei*, which means there are no costs attached to something and is the same as *kostenlos*. For some words you use the ending *-los* and for others you’d use *-frei* and for some you can use both to indicate a lack of whatever you appended those endings to.

- bedingungslos
- kostenlos/kostenfrei
- alkoholfrei

Comment: Very good answer, thanks. However, I'd love to see you perhaps expand that last paragraph a bit more.

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu Hope these examples help.

Comment: Nice answer. A note on typography: If a quote ends in a full stop and is at the end of a sentence, only one full stop is actually written. American English always includes the full stop (there termed *period*) inside the quotation marks, British English and German distinguish whether it can belong to the quote or not. In any case, if after a quote full sentence the original sentence continues, a comma is written but not a full stop.

Comment: @Jan Hey, thanks for tending to my post, I was not sure if it is consensus here to use italic words, so I used quotes. If I understand your explanation correctly, it means that the folling is wrong: _He said: "I am not free."._ because the _._ already marks the end of the phrase and the outer phrase doesn't need to be ended again. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, correct would be *He said: ‘I am not free.’* (or with double quotes, that’s personal preference.

Answer (score 5):

*Kostenlos* and *gratis* are synonyms and both mean *free* (at no charge). But note that *gratis* is not declinable, i. e. you can only say:

- Sie erhalten eine Ausgabe gratis.
- Sie erhalten eine Ausgabe kostenlos.
- Sie erhalten eine kostenlose Ausgabe.
- Sie erhalten eine Gratisausgabe (**wrong**: “gratise Ausgabe”).

*Umsonst* is an alternative in spoken language, but you will rarely see it on advertisements or in articles because *umsonst* also means *to no purpose* in German. *Umsonst* is not declinable either.

*Frei* basically means *in freedom*. I don’t recommend using it in place of *gratis*. However, *kostenfrei* is another possibility.

Comment: And remember the good old joke asking for the difference between *gratis* and *umsonst:* ‘Du bist gratis in die Schule gegangen, und ich umsonst.’ ;)

Comment: In "Freibier" oder "Eintritt frei" ist 'frei' nicht nur üblich sondern m.W. auch vorherrschend.